# Does this FastAPI Streaming Response Leave Any Hanging Resource Open?

Tags: python, arrays, fastapi

The goal is to return three pandas dataframes (`result1`, `result2` and `result3`) as three sheets in an excel file as response to a fastapi route. This is how the end of the function looks like

```
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse
...
with BytesIO() as buffer:
    # pylint: disable=abstract-class-instantiated
    with pandas.ExcelWriter(path=buffer, engine=XCL_ENGN) as writer:
        result1.to_excel(excel_writer=writer, sheet_name='Report 1', index=False)
        result2.to_excel(excel_writer=writer, sheet_name='Report 2', index=False)
        result3.to_excel(excel_writer=writer, sheet_name='Report 3', index=False)
    return StreamingResponse(content=BytesIO(initial_bytes=buffer.getvalue()), 
                             headers=headers)
```

The code is working as expected. However, the return statement seems to open a bytestream that forms the content being returned, but never operates `close()` on it. I tried wrapping that inside another with statement, but seems that throws a

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

I also tried the contextlib.closing method, but same error. So is there any resource being leaked here and how to avoid it?

Also, it seems when I am writing the data to the first buffer, then forming another bytestream just to return the value (which essentially copied everything, perhaps) kinda inefficient. Any way to make this part of the code cleaner and leakage free, adhering to best context management practices?

Comment: There's no point in using StreamingResponse in this code, since you've precomputed everything into a `BytesIO` that's in memory.

Comment: But to answer your question: no, this code won't leak, since the `BytesIO()` will be garbage collected once StreamingResponse is done with it.

Comment: So what should the return statement look like so that it would allow the user to download an excel file? Also, Would not any open resource be garbage collected upon a function return, such as if I had ```open(file='sample.txt')```, before return?

Comment: Yes, Python would eventually garbage collect the file and close it (and possibly throw a `ResourceWarning` about having had to do so).

Comment: Thanks for getting back, yes, even though I am not receiving the ResourceWarning, that is the scenario I am trying to avoid, to not depend on the garbage collector, but close the bytestream via my code itself, which is the purpose of ```with``` statement.

Comment: Closing a BytesIO makes it unusable as a file (and you can't call `.getvalue()` on it either). See my answer, please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, so long as it's okay to buffer the Excel worksheet fully into memory, `StreamingResponse` is not necessary here at all.

```
from fastapi.responses import Response

# ...

with BytesIO() as buffer:
    with pandas.ExcelWriter(path=buffer, engine=XCL_ENGN) as writer:
        result1.to_excel(...)
    data = buffer.getvalue()
return Response(content=data, headers=headers)
```

will do just fine.

If the worksheet is too large to keep in memory, then you could use e.g. a `tempfile.TemporaryFile` and a [background task](https://www.starlette.io/background/) to dispose of it once the response is written.